# Are windows based memory mapped files initialized to 0?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I've seen various claims either way, it seems that they are usually 0'd out but this might vary in some situations. For me its crucial that they would be initialized to 0 so is there any way to guarantee that? I don't want to be writing gigabytes worth of 0's on the disk if i don't have to.

Comment: You mean if you use it to create a new file of non-zero size?

Comment: I didn't know it could create a file by itself, right now I'm creating the file with CreateFile with OPEN_ALWAYS and setting its size with SetFilePointer / SetEndOfFile before passing the file handle over to CreateFileMapping

Comment: It is the same question but reading through that link, It doesn't look like he got a definitive answer.

Comment: Whatever the behaviour is, it comes from whatever `SetFilePointer()` or `SetEndOfFile()` do. It doesn't have anything to do with mapped files at all really.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp the second answer is perhaps better and the discussion in the comments sums it up: `CreateFileMapping` specifies that what happens depends on the file system, although as per the current implementation of `ZwSetInformationFile` the file is guaranteed to be zeroed. This may or may not hold for future implementations.